# Special name for first non abstract virtual method without code?

Tags: oop, inheritance, virtual-inheritance

This questions comes from another similar question. Sometimes I have to deal with this case.

Do you know if exist an special name in Object Oriented Programming, for a initial method that has been declared `virtual`, that is intentionally **not** `abstract`, but, does nothing, or does not have any code at all, but, maybe called ?

This example is pseudocode, but, applies to any O.O. programming language:

```
public class MyBaseClass 
{
  public abstract virtual void OverrideMe();
  public virtual void DoSomething() { cout << "Hello Mars\n" }
  public virtual void MayDoSomething() { /* Nothing, yet */ }
}

public class MyDerivedClass : MyBaseClass
{
  public override void OverrideMe() { cout << "Hello Neptune\n" }
  public override void DoSomething() { cout << "Hello Jupiter\n" }
  public override void MayDoSomething() { cout << "Hello Venus\n" }
}
```

The method `MyBaseClass::MayDoSomething()` its the case.

Cheers.

Comment: May I ask, why you might need such methods? Aren't they should be declared abstract, if they do nothing? Just wondering.

Comment: @Hnatt Those methods usually are helpers for other methods, not used by themselves.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a name for this *in general*, but I've heard various names for techniques that use this kind of method.  I would say it depends on the specific use.

- it could be an instance of [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)
- it could potentially be a [stub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_stub)
- it could be a [callback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_science%29) or [hook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_%28programming%29)

The only general name I can think of is a [NOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) method!

Comment: I know the NOP from some processors assembler, but its restricted to a particular overridable method.